# pictures with different modal

Tags: javascript, image, modal-dialog

I am fresh and new to JavaScript and eager to learn more about it.
I tried to do something with modals, and came across a difficulty that I cannot seem to solve.
I want to have four pictures next to each other and when I click on it, it displays a modal. So picture A shows modal A, picture B show modal B and so on. I can only seem to get the first picture working right now and the other pictures do not even show a modal.
Can somebody please help me with this? Thank you in advance

```
   <div class = "StyleTextBox">
    <h1>Present</h1>
    <img id="myImg" src="C:/Users/s155310/Pictures/showcase pictures/guitar1.jpg" alt="guitar" width="200" height="auto">
    <img id="myImg" src="C:/Users/s155310/Pictures/showcase pictures/1.jpg" alt="thing" width="200" height="auto">

  //The Modal
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
       <span class="close">×</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"> </div>
      <p> Some text </p>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

          // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
          var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
          var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
          var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
          img.onclick = function(){
              modal.style.display = "block";
              modalImg.src = this.src;
              modalImg.alt = this.alt;
              captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
          }

          // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

          // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
          span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
          }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is invalid HTML to have more than one element with the same ID. You should alter your image elements to instead use a class. In JavaScript you can then access these classes via `document.getElementsByClassName('classNameHere')` and iterate over them via a loop to set the onclick attribute. For example:

```
<div class = "StyleTextBox">
  <h1>Present</h1>
  <img class="myImg" src="C:/Users/s155310/Pictures/showcase pictures/guitar1.jpg" alt="guitar" width="200" height="auto">
  <img class="myImg" src="C:/Users/s155310/Pictures/showcase pictures/1.jpg" alt="thing" width="200" height="auto">

//The Modal
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"> </div>
  <p> Some text </p>
</div>

<script>
      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

      // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
      var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
      var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      function openModel(){
          modal.style.display = "block";
          modalImg.src = this.src;
          modalImg.alt = this.alt;
          captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      }
      for(var img = 0; img < images.length; img++) {
        images[img].onclick = openModel;
      }

      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
</script>
```

Comment: that works! Sorry just a beginner here (:
I still cannot seem to add different captions to each picture. I want to add more text than the alt attribute is used for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not using unique id's. Use classes instead